# Bitmap in Android: Size of resources for displaying as 50dp

Tags: android, image, resources, size, png

I have a PNG image that I want to display in my application.

In the layout file (.xml) I set the width and height to 50dp (density-independent). But what should be the size of my resource(.png) files?

I thought about this (calculation based on density ratios):

- ldpi resource: 38
- mdpi resource: 50 (base)
- hdpi resource: 75
- xhdpi resource: 100

Or is one png file in "/res/drawables" enough that is 50px wide?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to create 4 images. `mdpi` will be the baseline, meaning `mdpi` is 100%. Others follow this formula:

[image: drawables]

Place each image in the proper resource folder, `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`. Android will choose the proper drawable depending on the current device.

Then, in your layout simply `wrap_content` your width and height, there is no need to specify any fixed size:

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/my_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! What is your source for mdpi being the baseline? Why isn't it hdpi?

Comment: That's how android itself is designed. 1dpi is equal to 1px (physical pixel) on a 160dpi configuration, which is the reference value for mdpi. That's why mdpi is the baseline. The reason why they adopted this convention is that the first android device (the G1) featured an HVGA medium-dpi screen.

Comment: The Android docs discuss the baseline here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range

Comment: Thank you! You (both) helped me a lot! It is obvious that a medium density (normal size) display with 160dpi makes 1dpi equal to 1px. But what is the case for displays with 170dpi or values like that? As you can't say that every mdpi display is 160dpi (resolutions may vary in a given range). And due to the formula which you can see in Cata's answer, 170dpi make 1px unequal to 1dpi.

Answer (score 4):

It's not enough to have just one image. You have to put a different image in each resource folders (*drawables-ldpi*, *drawables-mdpi*, *drawables-hdpi* and *drawables-xhdpi*).

Please note that `50dp` is not equal with `50px`

You can make use of this formula:

**px = dp * (dpi / 160)**

You can find other useful tips [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).